# i want to disable save and discard button without using option such as create='false' ,edit='false'

Tags: odoo-10, oncreate, kanban

i want to disable save and discard button without using option such as create='false' ,edit='false' in odoo .

I have to give an option to create in kanban view ,and the new form should open without the save and discard button as i am adding my own custom button for that task.

Comment: You can give group to that buttons.

Comment: can you please explain.because i want to disable save and discard for all the users.

Comment: Create an group then set that id of group to that particular button. After that from **Settings** choose users to whom you want to show and set that group to that user.